# Create a column with boolean values for each label of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with a column reporting a tag for each line. 
How can I create a column for each tag and add a boolean value to each column containing the tag?

This my input table in the file input.csv

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 TAG
12    13   21   a
15    23   31   b
32    33   31   a
15    53   31   a
18    26   31   c
17    63   31   d
12    25   31   a
1     93   31   a
13    25   31   a
```

and this is what I am aiming to obtain

```
COL1 COL2 COL3  a  b  c  d  ...
12    13   21   1  0  0  0
15    23   31   0  1  0  0 
32    33   31   1  0  0  0
15    53   31   1  0  0  0
18    26   31   0  0  1  0
17    63   31   1  0  0  1
12    25   31   1  0  0  0
1     93   31   1  0  0  0
13    25   31   1  0  0  0
```

I tried to use pandas without success... 
Here is the piece of code I wrote

```py
import pandas

column_to_replicate='tag'

df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
col_names = df[column_to_replicate].dropna().unique().tolist()
df[col_names] = pd.get_dummies(df[column_to_replicate])
```

Comment: `df=df.join(df.pop('TAG').str.get_dummies())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)-encoding. You can use the function `get_dummies` for a corresponding result:

```py
import pandas as pd
one_hot_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df['TAG'])
one_hot_encoded.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @anky_91 works!

```
df=df.join(df.pop('TAG').str.get_dummies())
```